# ASP.NET MVC How to access Entity Framework generated foreign key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

`Song` has a many to many relationship with it's self. I store these ids in a class called `SimilarVersion` with both id columns.

```
public class Song
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string AudioName { get; set; }

    public string ArtistName { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<SimilarVersion> SimilarVersions { get; set; } = new List<SimilarVersion>();      
}

public class SimilarVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? Song_Id1 { get; set; }
}
```

View Models:

```
public class SongDto 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string AudioName { get; set; }

    public string ArtistName { get; set; }

    ...

    public ICollection<SimilarSongDto> SimilarSongDtos { get; set; } = new List<SimilarSongDto>();
}

public class SimilarSongDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string AudioName { get; set; }

    public string ArtistName { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The `SimilarVersion` table in my database now has `Id`,`Song_Id`,`Song_Id1`, as EF has generated Song_Id. How do I get to use that EF generated column in my code though?

`_similarVersionService.GetSimiliarVersion().Song_Id` will give me an error because there is no property in the class called that. I could manually add it to the class like I have done with `Song_Id1` and remove the collection from the other class but I think I must be doing something wrong. Also please tell me if there is a better way of mapping this.

I tried adding `public int Song_Id { get; set; }` and it just made another column in my table called `Song_Id2`.

```
public ActionResult Song(int id)
{
    //Map the domainModel to songViewModel
    var songDto = Mapper.Map<Song, SongDto>(_songService.GetSong(id));

    //Get all of the songs where the id == the Song_Id column in similar version table
    var songs = _songService.GetSongs().ToList()
                .Where(x => x.SimilarVersions.Any(z => z.Song_Id == songDto.Id))
                .ToList(); //z.Song_Id no definition found

    //Map the Song domain to SimilarSong ViewModel and assign it to the songDto to be passed to the view
    songDto.SimilarSongDtos = Mapper.Map<ICollection<Song>, ICollection<SimilarSongDto>>(songs);

    return View(songDto);
}
```

**Edit. Trying to add to a row based on Admir answer:**

```
var songToUpload = new Song
{
    AudioName = uploadSongDtos[i].AudioName.Trim(),
    ArtistName = uploadSongDtos[i].ArtistName,                        
};

 foreach (var compareAgainstString in _songService.GetSongs().ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.AudioName))
 {
       var score = SearchContext.Levenshtein.iLD(songToUpload.AudioName, compareAgainstString.Value);

       //Don't add the current song
       if (score < 50 && songToUpload.Id != compareAgainstString.Key)
           songToUpload.SimilarVersionsWhereSimilar.Add(new SimilarVersion { SimilarId = compareAgainstString.Key });
 }
```

Both `OriginalId` and `SimilarId` are assigned to whatever the id of `songToUpload.Id` is given the relationship we defined in models, which is correct for `OriginalId` but it is also overriding my custom set `SimilarId` above. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take this approach:

```
public class Song
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ArtistName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Similarity> SimilaritiesWhereOriginal { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Similarity> SimilaritiesWhereSimilar { get; set; } 
}

public class Similarity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OriginalId { get; set; }
    public virtual Song Original { get; set; }

    public int SimilarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Song Similar { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Similarity> Similarities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Song>().HasMany(x => x.SimilaritiesWhereOriginal).WithRequired(x => x.Original).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Song>().HasMany(x => x.SimilaritiesWhereSimilar).WithRequired(x => x.Similar).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Similarity class shows relationship between "original" song and "similar" song. This class replaces EF auto-generated table with your own many-2-many relationship table that you can access from the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been trying to add a row to the `SimilarVersion` table using your answer but it's not working as expected. I have edited my original question to show the problem. I also don't understand why we need `public virtual Song Original` and `public virtual Song Similar` in the `Similarity` table. I think maybe I am implementing it incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the ID is actually generated by your Store. Call `Context.SaveChanges()` to create it, *then* read the ID.

Comment: How do I read Id if there is no property on the class? It's a compile time error.

Comment: My phone made it difficult to read part of your question. EF6 makes it hard to access a join table property. Typically you get the object before getting its ID.